Hints for showing if $G$ acts on $M$ smoothly, properly, and freely, then $\pi:M\rightarrow M/G$ is principal $G$-bundle.
First, I start with a definition of a principal $G$-bundle (because apparently there are nonequivalent definitions): a principal $G$-bundle is a smooth $G$-manifold $P$ together with a manifold $B$ and a smooth map $P\rightarrow B$ so that $P$ is locally trivial with fiber $G$ and the local trivializations $\Psi:\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times G$ are $G$-equivariant with the action on $U\times G$ given by $g.(x,h)=(x,hg^{-1})$. (side question: is this definition standard and if not, then how "nonstandard" is it? Is it equivalent to the ones on Wikipedia?)
Let $G\times M\rightarrow M$ be a smooth, free and proper group action. By the quotient manifold theorem there exists a unique smooth structure on the quotient topology of $M/G$ so that $\pi:M\rightarrow M/G$ is a (surjective) smooth submersion.
I want to show that $\pi:M\rightarrow M/G$ is a smooth $G$-bundle. To this end, I want to check that given a local section $\sigma:U\rightarrow M$ of $\pi$, the following map is a diffeomorphism $$\psi:U\times G\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U),(x,g)\mapsto g^{-1}.\sigma(x)$$
Now $\psi$ is smooth. My goal is to show that $\psi$ is a bijective local diffeomorphism. It is injective since $$\psi(x',g')=\psi(x,g)\Rightarrow (g')^{-1}\sigma(x')=g^{-1}\sigma(x)\Rightarrow x'=\pi(\sigma(x'))=\pi((g')^{-1}\sigma(x'))=\pi(g^{-1}\sigma(x))=\pi(\sigma(x))=x$$
which then implies that $$g^{-1}\sigma(x)=(g')^{-1}\sigma(x)\Rightarrow g'g^{-1}\sigma(x)=\sigma(x)\Rightarrow g'=g$$
If $p\in\pi^{-1}(U)$, $[p]\in U$. On the other hand, since $\pi(\sigma([p]))=[p]$ then $\sigma([p])=g.p$ for some $g\in G$. So, $g.p=\sigma([p])\in \sigma(U)$, and, therefore, $p\in g^{-1}\sigma(U)$. This means that $\pi^{-1}(U)\subseteq \bigcup_{g\in G}g(\sigma(U))=\psi(G\times U)$. Thus, $\psi$ is surjective.
Now I need to show that it is a local diffeomorphism. And that's the first part where I'm stuck. I was thinking of showing that it is a covering map. But I'm not sure how.

Your proposal does not use properness of the action. Without this assumption the claim (of fiber bundle) is false.

@MoisheKohan see that’s what I initially thought, but the reason I think I am on the right track is that in problem 21.6 in LeeSM (which is basically this one), the hint is to use this map $\psi$ that I constructed (the map there is slightly different map, he takes $g\sigma(x)$ instead of $g^{-1}\sigma(x)$).

Let $(x,g) \in U \times G$ and $v_x \in T_x U$ and $w_g \in T_g G$. Suppose that
$$d\psi_{(x,g)}(v_x,w_g) = 0.$$
Let $\pi_U: U \times G \to U$ be the projection onto the first factor. Then $$0 = d\pi \circ d\psi_{(x,g)}(v_x,w_g) = d\pi_U(v_x,w_g) = v_x.$$
For all $y \in M$ define $\phi_y: G \to M, \ g \mapsto g\cdot y$. Then $\phi_y$ is an injective immersion for all $y \in M$ since $\phi_y$ is $G$-equivariant, which implies that $\phi_y$ has constant rank, and $\phi_y$ is injective because $G$ acts freely on $M$. In particular $$\phi_{\sigma(x)}\circ \iota$$ is an immersion, where $\iota: G \to G, \ g \mapsto g^{-1}$.
It is
$$0 = d\psi_{(x,g)}(v_x,w_g) = d\psi_{(x,g)}(0,w_g) = d(\psi(x,\cdot))_g(w_g) = d(\phi_{\sigma(x)}\circ \iota)_g(w_g)$$
and therefore $w_g = 0$. This implies $(v_x,w_g) = (0,0)$ and it follows that $\psi$ is an immersion.
Now, $\dim U\times G = \dim \pi^{-1}(U)$ which implies that $\psi$ is also a submersion hence a local diffeomorphism.

You did not use the properness assumption: Without this assumption the claim is false.

@MoisheKohan Well, it was "implicitly" used in the quotient manifold theorem to assure that $M/G$ is a smooth manifold, wasn't it?

That is not enough to guarantee a bundle.

@MoisheKohan I don't see what's wrong with my or the OP's proof? Do you have a counterexample? I think that it is indeed enough.

The result is true and I think it was discussed several times earlier on MSE. The standard proof uses existence of an invariant Riemannian metric and normal exponential map. What OP wrote does not address the question of injectivity which they might regard as trivial (and it is not).

@MoisheKohan Sorry, I don't really get it. The action is free so $\psi$ is injective, or do you mean something else?
